# Storing logs on Graylog

Tags: java, virtualbox, graylog2

I have an application in Java/Groovy and a [Virtual Machine Appliance](http://docs.graylog.org/en/1.0/pages/installation.html#virtual-machine-appliances) of Graylog running on VirtualBox.

How can I "make the connection" to store my logs on Graylog?

Comment: Probably over TCP. How have you configured the networking on the virtual machine? Does it have a static IP or DHCP, and if it's DHCP have you configured it to e.g. register itself with your DNS server with a domain name that you can use to reach it?

Comment: @Rup I did not do any of that. I'm looking for a "simple" way to use Graylog to store my logs, without having to make loose too much time on configuration.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your are using [this](https://github.com/Graylog2/graylog2-images/tree/master/ova) virtual machine. Assuming you need to create a new Graylog input and adapt the Logstash .conf to send logs with GELF:

1. Go on the Graylog web interface
2. Go in system/inputs section of the web interface
3. create a GELF UDP input and give it a name
4. Add the following line in your Logstash .conf, in the output section as follows:

   output {gelf {host => "my_VM_IP"}}
5. Start your Logstash instance.
6. Send a new log to Logstash.
7. Search for the latest logs in the Graylog web interface to check that it was received.